# Commencal META AM v4.2

Tags: suspension, lockout

I'm looking to purchase this bike, I'd like to know if it has lockout suspension but I can't seem to find it on the SPECS section.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Lockout is a function of the fork and shock. Look up the specs for these to find out. Out of interest I did this myself.

Fork - Lyrik RC has two position remote with setting Firm and Soft, does not appear to have lockout.

Shock - : RockShox Deluxe RT - External rebound, 2 position compression (Open/Pedal) again, does not appear to have lockout.

The question to ask is why do you want lockout. With modern shocks, especially those with 'pedal' modes, and bike geometries, lockout on an AM bike does not make sense, in that you do not buy an AM bike for its pedaling efficiency, and locking out such a bike does not magically make it perform like an XC bike.